# When using torch.eq(object, clone of that object) I encounter the error "bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous"

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

The inital problem arrised from the fact my predictions where non deterministic for the same input and I could not tell why so I started debuggging:

I read the data only once in a separete jupyter cell

```
input_data = skimage.io.imread(file_path)
dim = (320, 240)
input_data = cv2.resize(input_data, dim)
```

---

```
for i in range(5): #This section works without the commented lines
    mx, mn = np.max(input_data), np.min(input_data)
    if test.any() != input_data.any():
        break
    input_data_norm = (input_data - mn) / (mx - mn)
    input_data_reshape = input_data_norm.astype(np.float32).reshape(1,1,320, 240)
    file_tensor = torch.tensor(input_data_reshape).cuda()
    #if torch.eq(file_tensor_copy, file_tensor): ## From here comes my error 
    #     break
    plt.imshow(input_data, cmap='gray')    
    out = model(file_tensor)
    print(out)
    idx=int(np.argmax(out.cpu().detach().numpy(), axis=1))
    print(idx)
```

The output `out` shockingly always spitted out a different tensor for the same image so I wanted to se if the image/tensor changes.

Thus I start making a copy of said suspects :

```
test = input_data.copy()
file_tensor_copy = file_tensor.clone()
```

And when trying to use the commented lines and torch.eq respetively "I get bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous". The similar question that was answered referred to instantiating a loss something that is not the case here.

Extra Information: Classification Model using DenseNet.

Output of working code:

```
    tensor([[0.3508, 0.4329, 0.6930, 0.4736]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
2
tensor([[0.2466, 0.2795, 0.4258, 0.6313]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
3
tensor([[0.3825, 0.3196, 0.4442, 0.5798]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
3
tensor([[0.2423, 0.3352, 0.7914, 0.5401]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
2
tensor([[0.2853, 0.2779, 0.7428, 0.5389]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
2
```

Comment: Notify me if I have got your question wrong but what you want to do is to check if two tensors are the same, right? Then you should use [torch.equal](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.equal.html) instead of `eq`, since the function you used returns a tensor of booleans for each value of your tensor, while `torch.equal` returns a `True` if both tensors are the same and `False` otherwise.

Comment: You are correct.